# Excel VBA How to delete shape thats within the group

Tags: excel, shapes

I am beginner. I am trying to delete shapes in the given worksheet. If shapes are not grouped then the sub works but if the shapes are grouped it doesn't.

it still loops thru the shape but it seems that it cant delete it..

```
Sub DeleteShape(SheetName As String, ShapeName As String)
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Shapes
        If shp.Name = ShapeName Then
        shp.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat 'code' Sub DeleteShape(SheetName As String, ShapeName As String)
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Shapes
        If shp.Name = ShapeName Then
        shp.Delete
        End If
        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
            For Each subshp In shp.GroupItems
                If subshp.Name = ShapeName Then
                    subshp.Delete
                End If
            Next subshp
        End If
    Next
End Sub 'code'